# jest-cucumber : Feature file not found () error

Tags: jestjs, cucumberjs

I have a feature file, named as `consoleLogger.feature`.

and `consoleLogger.steps.js` which contains the below code ,

```
import { defineFeature, loadFeature } from 'jest-cucumber';
const consoleLogger = require('../src/Util/consoleLogger');
const feature = loadFeature('../feature/consoleLogger.feature');
```

I am trying to connect the feature file with the step definition file using `loadFeature` but getting the below error,

```
FAIL  steps/consoleLogger.steps.js
  ● Test suite failed to run
    Feature file not found (C:\Users\sr00015\NewWorkspace\feature\consoleLogger.feature)
```

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZEk9.png)

Comment: do you have a sample project which can be looked at? Alternatively, you can compare your code with `https://github.com/bencompton/jest-cucumber/tree/master/examples/ecmascript`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.
You must write the path of the feature from the root path.
For your example, it should be: ./tests/feature/consoleLogger.feature, meaning "tests" your tests/specs folder.